# Emgu CV Image width not multiple of 4

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, alignment, emgucv

i am trying to do some image processing with **Emgu CV**.

I have raw pixel data of a gray image in an **byte[]**. I know the size of the image and the type.

I first create an image width the known size an type and then i want to load the date to the image (I have often done this in **C++ OpenCV**).

```
Image<Gray, Byte> image = new Image<Gray, byte>(width, height);   
image.Bytes = data;
```

But the image is always kind of "cut through and puzzled together". It works with an image which **width%4 = 0**. That is why i assume it is some kind of "**memory alignment**" issue.

Has someone of you run into this problem and knows how to fix it?

Thanks,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Both your raw data and Image.Bytes are continuous pieces of memory. But every line of your array takes Width bytes, but line of Image takes Image.widthStep (I talk about IPLImage structure, don't know about Emgu pecularities) bytes, this value aligned for 4 bytes (99=>100 etc).
So you can or copy Width bytes for Yth line to Bytes[Y * widthStep] (height times), or create special 4-bytes-aligned array to collect raw data, then assign it to Image.Bytes

Answer (score 0):

try using another constructor:

```
Image<Gray, Byte> image = new Image<Gray, byte>(width, height, bytesNum, data);
```

See also http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.1.0.0/html/1d51c1ed-6f5e-65f9-206c-ef2d59c5c117.htm